# pyodbc: ORACLE SQL Statement with WHERE Clause that incorporates date range

Tags: python, oracle, datetime, where-clause, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to extract data from a database table. Now, **I would like to limit the query to only contain the records that were added within the last 24 hrs.** The information about the time a record was added is contained in the `DATE_ADDED` column .

This is what I am trying:

```
pyodbc.pooling = False
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient12Home1};'
   .....
   .....
   .....)

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
curs = conn.cursor()


date_today = datetime.datetime.today()
date_yesterday = date_today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

sql = f"SELECT PROD_ID, ID, COUNT, DATE_ADDED FROM LZE.APODAT WHERE DATE_ADDED < {date_today} AND DATE_ADDED  > {date_yesterday}"

my_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_sql(sql, conn))
```

The error message I get is:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position
>   218-219: illegal encoding

I'm sure it has to do with the different formatting/data types of the `DATE_ADDED` column but I am unsure how to approach this. In the database it looks as follows: `2019-04-24 10:21:05 AM`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to surround your dates with quotes: `'{date_today}'`

Comment: i tried that before. It gives me the same error

Comment: Does that help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478476/oracle-sql-query-for-date-format

Comment: if i try this: ```...  WHERE TRUNC(DATE_ADDED) < TO_DATE('{date_today}','YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS') AND TRUNC(DATE_ADDED) > TO_DATE('{date_yesterday}','YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')"``` 

i get the same error

Comment: Yes, I can extract the full table if I remove the where clause. Where would you suspect the special character? In the Database column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider parameterization (the industry standard when using SQL in application layer) as Python's `datetime` object may translate to Oracle's `date` type.

And yes, you can parameterize in Pandas with [`read_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) using the *params* argument (which does not need a `pd.DataFrame()` wrapper). Plus, you do not need F-strings, so this version can work in any Python version.

```
sql = """SELECT PROD_ID, ID, COUNT, DATE_ADDED 
         FROM LZE.APODAT 
         WHERE DATE_ADDED < ? AND DATE_ADDED  > ?
      """

my_df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, params=[date_today, date_yesterday])
```

Otherwise convert to string (removing decimal microseconds) and use Oracle's `TO_DATE()`:

```
sql = """SELECT PROD_ID, ID, COUNT, DATE_ADDED 
         FROM LZE.APODAT 
         WHERE DATE_ADDED < TO_DATE(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
           AND DATE_ADDED > TO_DATE(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')?
      """

my_df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, params=[date_today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 
                                       date_yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")]
                   )
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you want the last 24 hours...

You can say `DATE_ADDED >= SYSDATE() - 1.0` in a where clause to get that. `SYSDATE()` gets you the present moment. Dates in oracle behave like floating point numbers, where 1.0 is 24 hours. So subtracting 1.0 from the present moment gets you the same time yesterday.

If you want everything from midnight yesterday, you can [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2127.htm#OLADM705) the date.  Use

```
DATE_ADDED >= TRUNC(SYSDATE() - 1.0)
```

Comment: This makes the query a lot more tidy - but the I get the same error.